# Error when installing eZ Publish

Tags: composer-php, ezpublish

I have an error when I try to install eZ Publish by using the [installation instructions](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-community/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

```
cd /tmp/
git clone https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-community.git
```

The repository is correcly cloned, I then go to the  next step:

```
cd ezpublish-community/
composer install --prefer-dist
```

It installs the required packages then display this error message:

```
[...]
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Creating the "ezpublish/config/parameters.yml" file
Some parameters are missing. Please provide them.
secret (ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt): [...]
locale_fallback (en): 
ezpublish_legacy.default.view_default_layout ('eZDemoBundle::pagelayout.html.twig'): 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'eZ\Bundle\EzPublishCoreBundle\Kernel' not found in /tmp/ezpublish-community/ezpublish/EzPublishKernel.php on line 37
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
```

The `composer.json` file is the same as the [current one on github](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-community/blob/8f392ff9c8a1fddaff6cfad3dabc69bda79a5ab3/composer.json).

I have this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 and Debian wheezy (7.5).

### Update

Here is a solution but it should be noted that it will install the **development version of eZ Publish** (see the answer from **jeromegamez** below).

I was able to install eZ Publish by increasing the `memory_limit` parameter of PHP:

This didn't work (I don't know why and I don't care):

```bash
php -d memory_limit="1G" ./composer.phar install --prefer-dist
```

So I changed the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`file:

```ini
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
;memory_limit = 128M
; New
memory_limit = 1G
```

And the installation worked perfectly.

Comment: @RajatModi : no, I still have the same problem, even when I start a fresh install.

Comment: @RajatModi : I found a solution, please see the update of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master branch on github contains the bleeding edge of eZ Publish and might include not yet detected or newly introduced bugs. The error you are describing might be one of them, because just a moment ago (10 days after the date of your post), I executed the same steps as you described and everything worked fine.

If you don't need to participate in the development of eZ Publish, but rather want to look around in eZ Publish or create a new eZ Publish based project for your own needs, I would suggest downloading a release from the [official download page](http://share.ez.no/downloads/downloads) and follow the [installation instructions from the official documentation](https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/Installation).

Another nice and easy way would be to use

```
composer create-project ezsystems/ezpublish-community
```

which will get you set up with the latest release, without the need to manually clone repositories or to extract archives.

The current stable release is 2014.03, but eZ Systems is currently preparing a new (and much more feature complete and stable) release (2014.05), so it might be worth until it has been released to start with or continue the eZ adventure.

If you have more questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know the github repository is not the stable branch.

Comment: In fact the error in the question was due to the `memory_limit` parameter which was too low. But your explanation about the official documentation is perfect. Thanks again.